# How to get rid of the '\n' character while reading string from xsl?

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I'm reading xsl file using XSLReader class, and one of the columns contains strings but sometimes this string have enter in the (\n), so when I read this and print it I'm printing the string with the \n:

those are two addresses, the first one have enter in the xsl string, and the second doesn't...

```
VIALE SALVATORE REBECCHINI 39 \n00148 ROMA RM\n

viale castello della maglina,65-00148 roma
```

someone suggested some solution but it didnt work, i had to import common-lang3 and it looks like this:

```
this.supplierAddress = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(info[19]);
```

it suppose to ignore the \n but it dosen't..

anyone?

thanks!

Comment: Not sure how similar this is to coding for android but I use the \\ to get rid of the \ because the \ is a special character. So I would do \\n.

Comment: @TaylorCourtney I believe that's what `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with :

```
replaceAll("\\n","")
```

And escapeJava() is not what you need,  you need is unescapeJava() but like it says in the javadoc :

> Unescapes any Java literals found in the String. For example, it will
>   turn a sequence of '\' and 'n' into a newline character, unless the
>   '\' is preceded by another '\'.